# Can't check if Ruby object is capitalised

Tags: ruby, capitalize

I'm trying to check a condition:

```
name = gets.chomp  
if name.capitalized == name      
  puts 'some text'
else
  puts name.capitalize + 'some text'
```

im getting this error in the terminal:

> test.rb:6:in `<main>': undefined method`capitalized' for "name":String (NoMethodError)

Comment: And rightly so. There's no such method as `capitalized`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa Isn't it rather obvious?

Comment: @Juhana No, it isn't.

Comment: @Juhana That is not at all obvious. How did you know that? There is not a single mentioning of jQuery or HTML, not even in the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name = gets.chomp
if name.capitalize == name
      puts 'some text'
else
      puts name.capitalize + 'some text'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `capitalized?` method to `String`:

```
class String

  def capitalized?
    chars.first == chars.first.upcase
  end

end
```

You will be able to check if a string is capitalized and use that in your logic.

```
'Ruby'.capitalized?
 #=> true
```

EDIT: It seems that you are merely trying to capitalize the string itself and not check. In that case:

```
'ruby'.capitalize
 #=> 'Ruby'
```

Should do what you need.

Answer (score -1):

It is [String#capitalize](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize).try this.

This is a typo `if name.capitalized` change it to `if name.capitalize`